# Add labels x axis and y axis for streamlit line_chart

Tags: python, axis, linechart, streamlit

I would like to add labels for the x and y-axis for my simple `line_chart` in `streamlit`.

The plotting command is

```
st.line_chart(df[["capacity 1", "capacity 2"]])
```

which plots a `line_chart` with 2 lines (capacity 1 and capacity 2).

Is there a simple command to add the x and y-axis labels (and maybe a chart title too)?

Comment: PS I tried p = figure(
    title='simple line example',
    x_axis_label='x',
    y_axis_label='y')
st.line_chart(p, df[["capacity with charging", "capacity without charging"]]) which did not work..

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not supported by default by Streamlit, `st.line_chart()` is just a very quick way to call Altair's `mark_line()` method without any additional argument.

If you want to customize the plot further, you may simply use proper Altair:

```py
import streamlit as st
import altair as alt

chart = (
        alt.Chart(
            data=df,
            title="Your title",
        )
        .mark_line()
        .encode(
            x=alt.X("capacity 1", axis=alt.Axis(title="Capacity 1")),
            x=alt.X("capacity 2", axis=alt.Axis(title="Capacity 2")),
        )
)

st.altair_chart(chart)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the newest version [`v1.12.0`](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/charts/st.line_chart#stline_chart) you could use the arguments `x` and `y` to specify what you want to plot from your dataframe. `x` is:

> Column name to use for the x-axis. If None, uses the data index for
> the x-axis. This argument can only be supplied by keyword.

And `y` is:

> Column name(s) to use for the y-axis. If a sequence of strings, draws
> several series on the same chart by melting your wide-format table
> into a long-format table behind the scenes. If None, draws the data of
> all remaining columns as data series. This argument can only be
> supplied by keyword.

Here is a reproducible example using the dataset from the link above:

```
# import packages
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

# Example dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('seattle-weather.csv')

# plot
st.line_chart(data = df, x= "date", y = "temp_max")
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see it has labels for the x-axis and y-axis.